# Plone and systemctl

Tags: plone, systemd

I tried to integrate Plone with a systemctl based startup (on openSUSE 12.3)

As a first attempt I have a very simple plone.service file

```
[Unit]
Description=Plone content management system
After=network.target

[Service]
Type=simple
ExecStart=/srv/plone/zeocluster/bin/plonectl start

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Checking with systemclt status plone I see that the processes get started, but they immediatly vanish again. I've also tried Type=Daemon, but the endresult is the same.
Any hints were my error is?

The service actually finds/executes the plonectl script successfully, just the processes die quickly

```
linux-wezo:/etc/systemd/system # systemctl start plone.service
linux-wezo:/etc/systemd/system # systemctl status plone.service
plone.service - Plone content management system
          Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/plone.service; disabled)
          Active: inactive (dead) since Mon, 2013-03-18 22:00:50 CET; 1s ago
         Process: 25494 ExecStart=/srv/plone/zeocluster/bin/plonectl start (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
          CGroup: name=systemd:/system/plone.service

Mar 18 22:00:42 linux-wezo.site systemd[1]: Starting Plone content management system...
Mar 18 22:00:42 linux-wezo.site systemd[1]: Started Plone content management system.
Mar 18 22:00:43 linux-wezo.site plonectl[25494]: zeoserver: .
Mar 18 22:00:43 linux-wezo.site plonectl[25494]: daemon process started, pid=25502
Mar 18 22:00:46 linux-wezo.site plonectl[25494]: client1: .
Mar 18 22:00:46 linux-wezo.site plonectl[25494]: daemon process started, pid=25507
Mar 18 22:00:49 linux-wezo.site plonectl[25494]: client2: .
Mar 18 22:00:49 linux-wezo.site plonectl[25494]: daemon process started, pid=25522
```

I do have a SysV style init script, that works via systemctl, but think it would be great to have a service file since this should be more generic than the various init scripts floating around.

Comment: This question is more appropriate for superuser.com.

Comment: Are you starting both zeoserver and zeoclient(s)?

Comment: My first suspicion is that your problem is with permissions/identities. You've specified no user id for the service to run under. That might work if you'd set an explicit identity in your plone configuration. If you didn't, trying to start as root will fail. 
Check your event logs for clues.

Also, look to see if you've a package available for supervisor (sometimes called supervisord or python-supervisor. Installing it and using it to control your plone processes is a solid startup strategy.

Comment: Found the solution "Type=forking" does the trick as it seems. And it is case sensitive (I think I tried Type=Forking in an earlier attempt).

Answer (score 0):

The issue is the program plonectl is not a daemon, it is a wrapper script that starts Zope. You need to change the type to forking and probably to tell systemd where to find the PID file.

Answer (score 0):

Plonectl forks the daemon. Try this in plone.service:

```
[Unit]
Description=Plone content management system
After=network.target
ConditionPathExists=/srv/plone/zeocluster/bin/plonectl

[Service]
Type=forking
ExecStart=/srv/plone/zeocluster/bin/plonectl start
ExecStop=/srv/plone/zeocluster/bin/plonectl stop
ExecReload=/srv/plone/zeocluster/bin/plonectl restart

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```